# "ImportError: No module named _multiprocessing" in python 2.6

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, interix

It is my [understanding](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/multiprocessing/) that Python 2.6+ comes out of the box with multiprocessing. However, I am receiving an `ImportError: No module named _multiprocessing` called from `usr/local/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/__init__.py`, line 83. although `usr/local/lib/python2.6/` contains several *`_module`* files, `_multiprocessing` is not one of them.

What could cause this error on python 2.6?

I am running python on gcc3.4.6 via Interix3.5 on Windows XP SP3

Comment: Why are use using such old versions of Python and GCC? The bug might be fixed in a more recent version.

Comment: The versions are limited by what has been successfully ported to Interix3.5

Comment: I can tell you that _multiprocessing in an intrinsic of Python (located at /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_multiprocessing.so in my case). Are you sure that your Python version is compiled with multiprocessing capabilities?

Comment: I'm gussing that it must be by virtue of the fact that the directory /python2.6/multiprocessing/ exists. But that may be a faulty assumption. I'll examine further, thank you.

Comment: Did you get the same error with v2.7 as well?